# Smoother grid in a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a smoother grid in the background of this grid that's already plotted. This is what I've done so far. The grid follows my major ticks. I'd like this smoother grid to follow the minor ticks. Is this possible?

My code until now:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,10))

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0,round(max(datax)+1)))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(0,round(max(datay)+1),step = 0.1))
ax.minorticks_on()
ax.grid(True)
plt.xlabel("Tensão (V)", fontsize = 14)
plt.ylabel("Corrente (mA)", fontsize = 14)
plt.title("Experimento 2", fontsize = 20)
ax.errorbar(datax,datay,xerr = sigmax, yerr = sigmay, fmt = ',')
ax.set(xlim= -1, ylim = 0)
```

P.S.: would you guys organize this code differently? I think it's a complete mess.

[i want my grids to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gYrmn.png)
[this is how they are now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPKYM.png)

Comment: have you tried to use `ax.grid(True, 'both')` instead of `ax.grid(True)`?

Comment: Yes @Mehdi, but I need the grid that follows the minor ticks to be smoother.

Comment: You probably want to explain what you mean by "smoother".

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest i've edited with a better image to explain it

Comment: So you want a dashed linestyle for the grid? That would be `ax.grid(True, which="both", linestyle="--")`.

Comment: Not exactly, in the image there are two types of grids. One is related to the major ticks and the other with the minor ticks, that's what i want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `linestyle` keyword argument for `grid`, along with the `linewidth` keyword argument.

Here's how you can use dotted lines for your grid, with thinner lines for the minor ticks:

```
ax.grid(True, which='major', linestyle=':', linewidth=1, color="black")
ax.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5, color="black")
```

Here's the output (I used faked data since you did not provide a MWE):

[image]

You can fiddle with the `linewidth` parameter to have the lines appear thinner, or on the `color` to make them fainter.
You can also try other linestyles out, like dashed (`linestyle='--'`).